# On the use of the "min" function / operator in epsilon-delta limit proofs: how does " delta = min {a,b}" guarantee " delta <a AND delta < b"?

Tags: calculus, limits, soft-question, definition

Below a limit proof that requires in the end the use of the " min" function.

I know I have to use " delta = min {a,b} " but I do not understand clearly how the " min function" does the job.

Can it be shown formally that " *delta = min { 1, epsilon/15}* " guarantees that : 
"*( delta < 1 AND delta < epsilon /15)".*

My question : how to explain the step from (8) to (9) in the proof below?

Also: when checking a delta value in the form of  "*min { a, b}"*, do I have to proceed to a double verification, one for *a*, and one for *b*?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be precise,
$\delta = \min(a, b)$
means
$\delta \le a$
and
$\delta \le b$.

As a programming construct,
min can be defined as
min(a, b)
= if a $\le$ b then a else b.

So any proofs involving min
do have to consider all possibilities.

The inequality in the definition
can be either $<$ or $\le$ - 
it does not matter since
the result is the same
if $a = b$.

The result is that
$c = \min(a, b)
\implies (c \le a)
\land (c \le b)
$.

Answer (score 1):

Either $a \leq b$ or $b \leq a$.  The minimum is equal to one and less than the other.  So it's *less than or equal* to both.

If $|x-1| < \delta$, then either:
$$
    |x - 1 | < \delta = a < b
$$
or 
$$
    |x - 1 | < \delta = b < a
$$
Either way, $|x-1| \leq a$ and $|x-1| \leq b$ both hold.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm still confused. What I do not understand is how  " delta = min {a,b} " implies " delta < a AND delta <b". Could you please provide a proof for this? I tried a proof by cases , without success. Am I at least correct in believing that this implication is true? Assuming this is the only way I managed to explain to myself how the min operator does the job in the limit proof. What I mean is that I thought its job was to guarantee the antecendent in conditional (8)  could be made true.

Comment: It doesn't.  It implies $\delta \leq a$ and $\delta \leq b$.  (In fact, it's can't be true that $\delta < a$ and $\delta < b$; the minimum is equal to one of them.)  But if $|x-1| < \delta$, then $\delta \leq a$ tells you $|x-1| < a$, and $\delta \leq b$ tells you $|x-1| < b$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: You're welcome! This is a weird construction but once you get it, you'll see it applied elsewhere.